# Imagick convert CMYK JPG to PNG and transparency

Tags: php, png, jpeg, imagick, cmyk

I have a CMYK JPG file which I need to cut some parts from and then save into a CMYK PNG file. The problem is that even I just open the JPG file and save it into a PNG file the colors are shifted massively. I've been trying to fix that for a day now and have exhausted all available resources on SO and Google.

Here's my code:

```
$imageStick = new Imagick("original.jpg"); // CMYK JPG

$largeStick = new Imagick(); // create a bigger PNG file with transparent background
$largeStick->newImage($smallStick->getimagewidth(), $smallStick->getimageheight() * 3, new ImagickPixel('transparent'), 'png');

$largeStick->compositeimage($smallStick, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);

$largeStick->writeimage("resampled.png");
```

And here are the images:

[image: Original] - Original - [Download File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6pvovhk3cpj6giy/13945001-ftCMYK.jpg?dl=0%20Download%20file)

[image: Resampled] - Resampled

Any ideas why would that be happening?

I've tried copying all possible profiles and image properties from the original jpg file:

```
foreach ($smallStick->getimageprofiles() as $name => $profile)
    !empty($profile) && $largeStick->setimageprofile($name, $profile);

foreach ($smallStick->getimageproperties() as $name => $property)
    !empty($profile) && $largeStick->setimageproperty($name, $property);

$largeStick->setcolorspace($smallStick->getcolorspace());
```

manually setting up an ICC profile but no luck at all:

```
$icc_cmyk = file_get_contents('USWebUncoated.icc');
$largeStick->profileImage('icc', $icc_cmyk);
```

Any thoughts on this would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, the PNG format doesn't support CMYK colourspace, so I believe you are asking the impossible... see second paragraph  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Comment: OK, I may be wrong in that but the important thing here is that the colors are changing significantly when I transfer the image from jpg to png.

Comment: There is no accepted standard for CMYK in JPEG. Adobe has its own format but there isn't universal support for it. CMYK to RGB conversion is somewhat ill defined as well. How was the image created in the first place?

Comment: @user3344003 CMYK to RGB conversion using ICC profiles is quite well defined I think. Most CMYK JPEGs does contain an ICC profile.

Comment: The problem is the gamut.

Comment: The image comes from a DSLR - it's product photography done by a professional photographer and then converted to TIFF for print and JPG for web use. As far I can see there's an ICC profile already embedded in the JPG file.

Comment: The file purports to be in Adobe format but Photoshop says the ICC profile is invalid.

Comment: Deleted my answer as it was wrong - there is something weird with that source file. Normally you can transformColorSpaces and have the image look the same without much difficulty - but there is something odd happening with that file. Maybe try doing the conversion with just the command line 'convert' tool of ImageMagick, to at least reduce the possibility of Imagick doing something wrong?